# ActionCable and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I built a rails app that functions as a bike store.  Users are able to rate and comment on any given product and the idea is to use ActionCable and JavaScript (along with a bit of jQuery) to display the comments to various users subscribed to the ProductsChannel in real time.

I've got ActionCable mounted on my routes.rb file

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, :path => '', :path_names => {:sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout'}, :controllers => { :registrations => 'user_registrations'}

  resources :users 
  resources :products do
    resources :comments
  end

  resources :orders, only: [:index, :show, :create, :destroy]

  resources :payments

  mount ActionCable.server => '/cable'

  get 'static_pages/about'

  get 'static_pages/contact'

  get 'static_pages/index'

  root 'static_pages#landing_page'

  post 'static_pages/thank_you'

  get 'orders/index'

  get 'users/new'

  get 'products/new'

  get '/products/:id/edit' => 'products#edit'

  post 'payments/create'

  get 'comments/edit'

  #get 'products/:id' => 'products#show'#

  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

I created a ProductsChannel through the `rails g channel product` command in my terminal.

```
class ProductChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel

 def subscribed
  stream_from "product_channel"
 end

 def unsubscribed
 # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
   stop_all_streams
 end
end
```

My create action in my comments controller is set up so that when a comment is created, ActionCable will broadcast it through the ProductChannel to any user currently viewing any particular product.

```
    class CommentsController < ApplicationController
     before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def create
    @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @comment = @product.comments.new(comment_params)
    @comment.user = current_user
    #@user = request.env['warden'].user
    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        ActionCable.server.broadcast 'product_channel', comment: @comment, average_rating: @comment.product.average_rating   
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Review was created successfully.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @product }
        format.js
      else
        format.html { redirect_to @product, alert: 'Review was not saved successfully.' }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

I also have a `create.js.erb` file that goes hand in hand with the create action listed above.  The jQuery code inside this `create.js.erb` contains a few lines of code that will display an alert once a user posts a comment on a product page and it looks like so:

```
$('#new_comment').html("Thank you for your review!");
$(".alert.alert-info.mine").show();
$('.product-reviews').prepend("<%= j render @comment %>");
$("#average-rating").attr('data-score', "<%= @product.average_rating %>");

refreshRating();
```

This works fine but the end goal is to only notify users if a comment was posted on the product they're viewing at that moment. In my terminal, I can view what the connection looks like:

```
ProductChannel is transmitting the subscription confirmation
ProductChannel is streaming from product_channel
```

So I figured I would create a custom method inside my `ProductChannel.rb` file that would stream to a particular Product page based on its id.  Meaning that the alerts will only show if two or more users are viewing the same product page and one of them posts a comment.

With this in mind, I modified the `ProductChannel.rb` to look like this:

```
class ProductChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def listen(data)
    stop_all_streams
    stream_for data['product_id']
  end

  def subscribed
    #stream_from "product_channel"
  end

  def unsubscribed
    # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
    stop_all_streams
  end
end
```

I created a new method called `listen` and instead of streaming throughout the entire `ProductChannel`, I gave it an argument of `data` and passed the product_id as the argument so the notices only get displayed on a particular page that multiple users may be viewing.

Inside the `product.js` file that was created by Rails when I generated by `ProductChannel` (app/assets/javascripts/channels/product.js), I created a method that would tell the `listen` method from above to look for the `product_id` as its reference for where to direct the stream.

```
App.product = App.cable.subscriptions.create("ProductChannel", {
  connected: function() {
    // Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server
  },

  disconnected: function() {
    // Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server
  },

  received: function(data) {
    // Called when there's incoming data on the websocket for this channel
  },

  listen_to_comments: function(){
    return this.perform('listen', {
      product_id: $("[data-product-id]").data("product-id")
    });
  }
});
```

In order for this to work properly, I had to also to change some of the code inside my `create` action in my comments controller from this:

```
ActionCable.server.broadcast 'product_channel', comment: @comment, average_rating: @comment.product.average_rating
```

To this:

```
ProductChannel.broadcast_to @product.id, comment: @comment, average_rating: @product.average_rating
```

This helps reference an individual show page belonging to a particular product_id instead of flashing the notice on all the product pages.  The result in my terminal is this:

```
ProductChannel is transmitting the subscription confirmation
ProductChannel#listen
ProductChannel is streaming from product:
Started GET "/cable" for ::1 at 2016-11-26 13:53:19 -0500
Started GET "/cable/" [WebSocket] for ::1 at 2016-11-26 13:53:19 -0500
```

So the `listen` method is being called upon and the stream seems to relate to the product_id.  Now I finally come to the point where I get to present my problem and hope someone can help me figure out what is wrong.

Seeing how some of the code in my `create.js.erb` file would be a bit redundant, I figured I would move it to the `received` function in my `product.js` file like this:

```
received: function(data) {
    // Called when there's incoming data on the websocket for this channel
    $(".alert.alert-info.mine").show();
    $('#new_comment').html("Thank you");
    $('.product-reviews').prepend(data.comment);
    $("#average-rating").attr('data-score', data.average_rating);

    refreshRating();
  },
```

So this is the crux of the problem here.  The jQuery code above employed AJAX functionality to render the new comment immediately as well as flashing a notice to any user on that channel that a new comment was posted.  Once I moved the jQuery code to the `received` function, none of it works anymore.  This is my first time trying to implement ActionCable into an app and it's been pretty self explanatory thus far but this particular issue with jQuery has me stumped. I've spent the last three days looking for different ways to make it work to no avail.  Is there something I'm missing with regards to these functions inside the JS file created by rails when I generated my ProductsChannel?